# Probability that two integers chosen at random from an arithmetic progression are coprime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, arithmetic-progressions

It is well known that every coprime arithmetic progression (AP) contains an infinite number of prime numbers.

And also that the probability of $2$ random integers being coprime is $\dfrac{6}{\pi^2}$.

What is the probability of $2$ integers chosen at random from an admissible AP are coprime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two arbitrary integers $a$ and $b$ are coprime if and only if there is no prime $p$ such that $p|x$ and $p|y$. These conditions are independent, so the probability a given $p$ divides $a$ and $b$ is $p^{-2}$. These conditions are independent as $p$ varies, so the probability $b$ and $b$ are coprime is
$$
\prod_p\left(1-p^{-2}\right)=\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}.
$$
With a little care this probabilistic argument can be made rigorous.

Let $k$ and $n$ be coprime integers. If we restrict $a$ and $b$ to be congruent to $k$ modulo $n$ (where $k$ and $n$ are coprime), then no prime dividing $n$ can divide $a$ or $b$. For $p\nmid n$, the probability $p$ divides $a$ and $b$ is unchanged. So, the probability $a$ and $b$ are coprime is
$$
\prod_{p\nmid n}\left(1-p^{-2}\right)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}\prod_{p|n}\left(1-p^{-2}\right)^{-1}.
$$

Comment: what about $p|k$?

Comment: If $p|k$ (but $p\nmid n$), it is still true that an integer congruent to $k$ mod $n$ is divisible by $p$ with probability $1/p$. In this sense primes dividing $k$ are no different than other primes that don't divide $n$.

Comment: Adding to Julian Rosen's comment: the AP represented by $k$ is also represented by $n+k$, and none of the primes dividing $k$ also divide $n+k$. Moral: don't try to work with divisibility properties of *representatives* of residue classes. Only the primes dividing the modulus matter. (Example: modulo 15, it doesn't make sense to say some residue classes are even or odd.)

Comment: @GregMartin; is it because $3\mod15$ e.g. is odd/even/odd/even...($3,18,33,48,...$)

Comment: so if i consider $1,3,5,7\mod8$ then $k$ makes no difference?

Comment: what if $n$ is not squarefree

Comment: This should still be fine if $n$ is not squarefree (the product is over distinct primes dividing $n$).

Comment: Did you mean the probability $\color{red}a$ and $b$ are coprime where you typed $b$ and $b$?